# how to add content in checkout page magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, phtml

[image]

I need to add my own content in this area which is checkout page. I can't find the phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

**This block rendered from `summary.html` of `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html`**

You can add your custom content after overriding this file in your theme

**From**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html

**To**

> app/design/frontend/vendor/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html

Now run following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Also need to flush browser cache

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think that to add content to specific areas of the order summary you would need to go to the **`checkout_cart_index.xml`** and add you blocks within the container.